# Spring mongoTemplate find special column

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

Can i use mongoTemplate or other class/interface to find one/several column(s) in a collection?

For example, if i want to get only the name from collection: users(name, password, age, email)
, how could i do?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the fields returned by the query with `Query.fields()` method.

So in your case, assuming that user collection is mapped to `User` class the query could look like this:

```java
Query query =new Query(whatever criteria you have);
query.fields().include("name");
List<User> list = template.find(query, User.class);
```

Another way would be o extends a MongoRepository and specify fields qith `Query`annotation:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

   @Query(fields="{ 'name' : 1}")
   List<User> findUserNames();

}
```

`findUserNames` should return `User` instances with only name and id fields initialized.

**edit**

By the looks of it `spring-data-mongo` doesn't have a converter to `String` registered so you have to either retrieve `User` with all the fields except the ones included in the query set to `null` or create and register a converter.

Comment: use template can get List<String> of names?

Comment: @user1755541 not sure if mongo has the converter registered for DBObject to String, but you can try that easly (just change User to String). You certainly can get a Map with only `name` element set.

Comment: @user1755541 it looks like you can't by default.

Comment: Thank you, and now use "foreach" to change List<User> to List<String>

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Guava to solve your problem. 
Of course, You can use standard foreach construction, 
but in my opinion Guava is faster to implement and well tested.

Here is the link with good example
http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/002-transform-objects-with-guava/